# Getting an error while awaiting reaction using "wait_for" discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, attributes, tuples, discord.py

Getting this error while awaiting reaction to a message which the bot send before to the user dms

```
reaction = await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
  await player.user.send("you have selected %s lol"%(members[0]))

Error:

'tuple' object has no attribute 'emoji'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When waiting for a reaction the `wait_for` method returns two values - `discord.Reaction` and `discord.User` instances. To fix your code:

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
```